# How can I change some of the system sounds?

Tags: sound-theme

How can I change sounds in Ubuntu? Mainly I mean the sounds for startup, shutdown and warnings.

Comment: This was posted 6 years ago but came up in my search.  Here in July 2017, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I don't see any procedure to activate the sounds, even though I have found them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, themes are still in the works. While you can select a theme in the sound settings, you can't create or install any new ones. If you still really want to change the sounds, replace the corresponding files in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo`.

Answer (score 2):

The sounds are in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo`. Those files are in **.ogg** format.

Just replace them with yours with the same name and extension.

**Warning** : *make sure you do a backup of this directory before you start to change.*

Comment: Here in July 2017 I don't see how to turn them on in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: @SDsolar see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Since 15.10 the files are now in a folder like (in GNOME) `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/*.ogg` (there are other `sounds/*` folders).

Unfortunately adding more files does not change the list in the Sound application, that list is stored elsewhere -- you will have to copy and rename the existing files.

> ```
> .
> ├── alsa
> │   ├── Front_Center.wav
> │   ├── Front_Left.wav
> │   ├── Front_Right.wav
> │   ├── Noise.wav
> │   ├── Rear_Center.wav
> │   ├── Rear_Left.wav
> │   ├── Rear_Right.wav
> │   ├── Side_Left.wav
> │   └── Side_Right.wav
> ├── freedesktop
> │   ├── index.theme
> │   └── stereo
> │       ├── alarm-clock-elapsed.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-front-center.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-front-left.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-front-right.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-mono.oga -> audio-channel-front-center.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-rear-center.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-rear-left.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-rear-right.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-side-left.oga
> │       ├── audio-channel-side-right.oga
> │       ├── audio-test-signal.oga
> │       ├── audio-volume-change.oga
> │       ├── bell.oga
> │       ├── camera-shutter.oga
> │       ├── complete.oga
> │       ├── device-added.oga
> │       ├── device-removed.oga
> │       ├── dialog-error.oga -> dialog-warning.oga
> │       ├── dialog-information.oga
> │       ├── dialog-warning.oga
> │       ├── message-new-instant.oga
> │       ├── message.oga
> │       ├── network-connectivity-established.oga -> device-added.oga
> │       ├── network-connectivity-lost.oga -> device-removed.oga
> │       ├── phone-incoming-call.oga
> │       ├── phone-outgoing-busy.oga
> │       ├── phone-outgoing-calling.oga
> │       ├── power-plug.oga -> device-added.oga
> │       ├── power-unplug.oga -> device-removed.oga
> │       ├── screen-capture.oga -> camera-shutter.oga
> │       ├── service-login.oga
> │       ├── service-logout.oga
> │       ├── suspend-error.oga
> │       ├── trash-empty.oga
> │       ├── window-attention.oga -> dialog-warning.oga
> │       └── window-question.oga -> dialog-warning.oga
> ├── gnome
> │   └── default
> │       └── alerts
> │           ├── bark.ogg
> │           ├── drip.ogg
> │           ├── glass.ogg
> │           ├── sonar.ogg
> │           └── sonar_old.ogg
> ├── GNUstep
> ├── sf2
> │   ├── FluidR3_GM.sf2
> │   └── TimGM6mb.sf2
> ├── sound-icons
> │   ├── at -> cembalo-6.wav
> │   ├── beginning-of-line -> glass-water-1.wav
> │   ├── canary-long.wav
> │   ├── capital -> percussion-10.wav
> │   ├── cembalo-10.wav
> │   ├── cembalo-11.wav
> │   ├── cembalo-12.wav
> │   ├── cembalo-1.wav
> │   ├── cembalo-2.wav
> │   ├── cembalo-3.wav
> │   ├── cembalo-6.wav
> │   ├── chord-7.wav
> │   ├── cockchafer-gentleman-1.wav
> │   ├── cymbaly-1.wav
> │   ├── electric-piano-3.wav
> │   ├── empty-text -> gummy-cat-2.wav
> │   ├── end-of-line -> violoncello-7.wav
> │   ├── finish -> trumpet-1.wav
> │   ├── glass-water-1.wav
> │   ├── guitar-12.wav
> │   ├── guitar-13.wav
> │   ├── gummy-cat-2.wav
> │   ├── hash -> percussion-28.wav
> │   ├── klavichord-4.wav
> │   ├── left-brace -> pisk-up-cink.wav
> │   ├── left-round-bracket -> pisk-up.wav
> │   ├── left-square-bracket -> guitar-13.wav
> │   ├── message -> cymbaly-1.wav
> │   ├── percussion-10.wav
> │   ├── percussion-12.wav
> │   ├── percussion-28.wav
> │   ├── percussion-50.wav
> │   ├── piano-3.wav
> │   ├── pipe -> pipe.wav
> │   ├── pipe.wav
> │   ├── pisk-down-cink.wav
> │   ├── pisk-down.wav
> │   ├── pisk-up-cink.wav
> │   ├── pisk-up.wav
> │   ├── prompt -> prompt.wav
> │   ├── prompt.wav
> │   ├── right-brace -> pisk-down-cink.wav
> │   ├── right-round-bracket -> pisk-down.wav
> │   ├── right-square-bracket -> guitar-12.wav
> │   ├── start -> xylofon.wav
> │   ├── trumpet-12.wav
> │   ├── trumpet-1.wav
> │   ├── violoncello-7.wav
> │   └── xylofon.wav
> └── speech-dispatcher
>     ├── dummy-message.wav
>     └── test.wav
>
> 10 directories, 104 files
> ```