# Get first Ubuntu startup sound in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, startup

I've seen that Ubuntu had two startup sounds, and if you make a startup app that executes the command `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"` , or just execute it in terminal, it plays the new startup sound (before 11.04).

I want to play the old one from 6.06 LTS Dapper Drake. Is it still in 14.04 or will I have to download the sound? Then how can I make it play? [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8JivuODUwE) the sound I'm talking about.

How can I also get the shutdown sound too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the zipped sounds from my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fudjktaqo0c5p4/sounds.zip).

The startup sound is a .wav, you can convert it to a .ogg using VLC or Audacity. The shutdown sound is already a .ogg.

To change it, please look at [How do I change the start up sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138760/how-do-i-change-the-start-up-sound) or [How can I change some of the system sounds?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9246/how-can-i-change-some-of-the-system-sounds)

---

The shutdown sound in the zip above is corrupted.
I have uploaded a correct version of the shutdown sound both .ogg and .mp3 files. [Download here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciix96rtzrfneh7/shutdown.zip)

---

## My Process

1. I searched Google for 'Ubuntu 6.06 startup sound' and got [this youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmenqmNDT4A).
2. I used [Youtube To Mp3](http://www.mediahuman.com/repository.html) by MediaHuman to download the mp3 version of the sound.
3. I used audacity to convert the Mp3 to a .ogg.

Comment: When I try to open the shutdown sound with Audacity, the program states it's corrupted, nothing happens in VLC, but when trying to open the startup sound in VLC, it plays, Audacity also seems to open it, any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: It was corrupted, I have uploaded the correct version.

Comment: Also, I get an error saying "Failed to play sound: Sound disabled." after replacing the system boot sound, the ogg file does not seem to be corrupted and is located in my music folder. (I replaced /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg with a converted version of the startup sound you sent by using [this website](http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg)

Answer (score 1):

Seems the old sound is not there any longer, I could not find it in all of *.ogg, *.wav files.

You can change the sound yourself:

```
cd /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/    
sudo cp desktop-login.ogg desktop-login.ogg.sav    
sudo cp ~/Downloads/desired-sound.ogg desktop-login.ogg
```

Comment: After this, I get an error saying "Failed to play sound: Sound disabled." For some reason it only outputs on the command line...

Comment: So you finally were able to follow this, I happy to know you got success with this.

Comment: Yeah, but replacing the sound doesn't make it play, I did exactly this and get an error, so, in reality, no success...

Comment: It works for me, just double checked right now, changed (overwritten) the `desktop-login.ogg` with the `desktop-logout.ogg` and it played different now.